# CSS fullscreen grid layout (with some scrolling sections)

Tags: css

So, it's 2010 and I still don't know how to do this layout in CSS..

Sorry if this has an obvious answer, I appreciate any help you could offer.

I've seen close solutions for parts of this, but not all of these combined.

[image]

1. The layout must always fill the screen (unknown dimensions and dynamic resize)
2. A, D, C, F are fixed height (e.g. 64px)

   - B and E must expand to fill the remaining vertical space.
   - If either B or E run out of room, a vertical scrollbar should appear (only within its area; B and E should scroll independently of each other).
3. A, B, C are fixed width (e.g. 300px)

   - D, E, F must expand to fill the remaining horizontal space.
4. A, B, C are semantically related content.
5. D, E, F are semantically related content.
6. No other scrolling should occur apart from 2 above.
7. C is optional
8. Newer browsers only, I don't care about IE6 or 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I struggled with this for a while...the result is much easier than expected, however.

```
A {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: #px;
    width: #px;
}
B {
    position: absolute;
    top: {height of A};
    left: 0;
    width: #px;
    bottom: {height of C};
    overflow-y: scroll; /* note that the scrollbar will always be visible */
}
C {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: #px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: #px;
}
D {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: {width of A};
    right: 0;
    height: #px;
}
E {
    position: absolute;
    top: {height of D};
    left: {width of B};
    right: 0;
    bottom: {height of F};
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
F {
    position: absolute;
    left: {width of F};
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: #px;
}
```

Note that #px should be replaced by the size.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great CMC, thanks so much!

I tried an approach with "display: table", but got stuck on the scrolling issue.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I needed to do that, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was struggling with a very similar problem, this seems to have resolved it.