# Setting the min-height of a div within the zurb-foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, css

I've just been introduced to the Zurb Foundation 4 framework via a friend of mine. Interesting stuff. But i'm having a problem I can't seem to understand. I have a site based on 4 rows (header, navbar, content, footer);

```
<div class="row siteBase">

   <div class="row siteHeader" id="siteHeader">
     <div class="large-12 c7olumns">
       <h2>Welcome to Foundation</h2>
       <p>This is version 4.1.2.</p>      
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row siteNavbar" id="siteNavbar">      
    navbar
   </div>

   <div class="row siteBody" id="siteBody">
    base
   </div>

   <div class="row siteFooter" id="siteFooter">
    footer
   </div>

</div>
```

here's my CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.siteBack {
    background-color: #545454;      
}

.siteBase { 
    /*base size and color*/
    width: 1280px;      
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;  

    /* exact fit the contents to the border */
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;

    /* border size and color */
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 4px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-color: #7da500;

    /* add some shadows to the borders */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #272727;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #272727;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #272727;
}

.siteHeader
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #7da500;
}

.siteNavbar
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.siteBody
{
    min-height: 100% auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;  
}

.siteFooter
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #7da500;
}
```

The problem I have is that the sitebody div isn't stretched to to full 100%. The header and navbar is fixed size, as is the footer. But I wan't the sitebody div to take the remaining space so that the footer is always placed in the lower bottom of the screen (at minimum).

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You'll want to have a fixed width on the body tag as well

Comment: Hi Nina, apologies for my late reaction, busy days. Tried setting the fixed with on the Body, doesn't work. only thing that happens is that my complete layout shifts to the left, but the footer is still right below the base, instead of hovering towards the bottom. in the meantime i also tried creating a small js script that determines the height of the viewport dynamically (right on load) and specifies a min-height for the body in pixels. but that didn't work eiter, the zurb framework got in between :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to stick your footer to the bottom of the page. In that manner you will have a full body even if your main content is small. You can take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676196/zurb-4-separately-scrollable-sections) to see how it is implemented. There could be a lot going on in there as that layout is a bit complex. So I did a sample for you that you can use for [a more simple layout](http://jsfiddle.net/RE93S/1/). Here is the modified css from the other SO question.

```
html, body, #wrapper{ height: 100%; }
body > #wrapper{height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#main { padding-bottom: 75px; /*  same height as the footer */
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 75px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;            
    background-color:yellow;           
}  
#footer { 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -75px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 75px;
    clear:both;
} 

.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
```